# Moving 3d Shape in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++, glut

I am writing a program in OpenGL/C++ that creates a number of Spheres and then moves them close to the screen until they are out of sight.
I understand how to create the Spheres, but I can't seem to figure out how to move them after they are created. Does anyone know how I can effectively change the move() function so that it increaces z by 1 each time it is called? Or if there is a better way to do this please let me know. Thanks!

```
 class Sphere {

public:
    double x, y, z;
    void create(double newx, double newy, double r, double g, double b) {
        x = newx;
        y = newy;
        z = -175; // start at back of projection matrix
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(x, y, z);
        glColor3f(r, g, b);
        glScalef(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glutSolidSphere(1, 50, 50);
        glPopMatrix();
    }
    void move() {
        glPushMatrix();
        //if z is at front, move to start over in the back
        if (z >= 0) {
            z = -176;
            x = rand() % 100;
            y = rand() % 100;
            x = x - 50;
            y = y - 50;
        }
        x = x;
        y = y;
        glPushMatrix();
        z++;
        glTranslatef(x, y, z);
        glPopMatrix();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenGL there are no "models created. In fact there are not even "models" in OpenGL. All there is, is a digital canvas, called a framebuffer, and drawing tools offered by OpenGL to draw points, lines and triangles, one at a time. The moment you drew something with OpenGL it already forgot about it.

Hence the whole notion naming a function "create" is wrong. Instead what you have there is a "draw" function.

So what you have to do is simple: Redraw the scene, but with your geometry at a different position.

Comment: So since OpenGL forgets about the shape it has made, to delete shapes and redraw them again, do I need to clear the whole screen using glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) and then redraw ?

Comment: @Sarah: That's the general idea yes. Just remember: OpenGL doesn't know what a "scene" is. There's just point, lines, triangles and the pixels in a framebuffer. Keep that in mind and *everything* related to OpenGL becomes much, much easier. When programming OpenGL is makes a lot of sense to think as things happening as pixels in screen space; and doing things by maniupulating images is perfectly in order.

Answer (score 3):

In order to change the position of your sphere, it is not necessary to call the glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix() functions in your move() function. You can simplify your move() function to this:

```
    void Move() {
        //if z is at front, move to start over in the back
        if (z >= 0) {
            z = -176;
        }
        z++;
    }
```

Furthermore, like user datenwolf said, you don't *create* but you 'Draw' or 'Render' a sphere (or whatever 3D object it is you want OpenGL to display).To give you an example, let's go with Render.

What you want is to create a Render() function and move the code from your create() function to it. Because you want to move the position of the sphere later on, move the x,y and z coordinates to the Sphere's constructor  and initialize them.

Example:

```
 class Sphere {
  public:
    double x,y,z;

    // We also set the color values of the sphere inside the sphere's
    // constructor for simplicity sake.
    double r,g,b;

   Sphere(double _x, double _y, double _z) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        z = _z;

        r = 1.0;
        g = 0.0;
        b = 0.0;

    }
    void Render() {
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(x, y, z);
        glColor3f(r, g, b);
        glScalef(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glutSolidSphere(1, 50, 50);
        glPopMatrix();
    }

};
```

OpenGL uses a callback function called glutDisplayFunc(). You pass a function to this glutDisplayFunc() in order to render everything you want to show on screen. I will call the function to be passed "void Render3DEnvironment()". You need to locate your glutDisplayFunc() and the function that is passed to it and call your sphere's Render() function there.

Here's an example:

```
#include "Sphere.h"

Sphere* sphere;

void Render3DEnvironment()
{
    sphere->Render();
    sphere->Move();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

    sphere = new Sphere(50,50,50);

    glutDisplayFunc(Render3DEnvironment);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;

}
```

The glutDisplayFunc() function will constantly be calling the function that has been passed to it, in this case the Render3DEnvironment() function. As you can see, the Move() function is also called in the Render3DEnviroment() function. This means that your sphere is also moving (rapidly) on the z axis and jumping back to -176 when z reaches a value equal to 0 or greater than 0.

**Tip**: Use GLfloat instead of double as data type for your x,y,z and r,g,b variables as the OpenGL functions in question use GLfloat variables. Saves you some compiler warnings.